# I can't change the type of numbering on sections

Tags: sectioning

My institute has specific rules for thesis. One of them is sectioning. First image is our institute's type, second is default latex type. But I can't change dafault type. I want to put a point after the number. Please help me.
[image: Giriş]

[image: Giriş 2]

Comment: Welcome! Try `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}`. For more advanced options look at the `titlesec` package.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Do you also need to get rid of the space between "1." and "GIRIS"?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat That's usually not the right solution, because the period will also appear in all cross-references. And subsection numbers will appear with *two* consecutive periods, unless you also change `\thesubsection`.

Comment: @egreg Well, this is why I was mentioning `titlesec`. This takes care of all these little things.

Comment: Crosspost on LaTeX.org: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=33024

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works with a low-level LaTeX macro called `\@seccntformat`. It inserts a dot after the section number *and* deletes the whitespace after the section number. With this setup, cross-references to sections will continue to work as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel} % is this correct?

% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.:
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.}% section-level: period, no space
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{G\.IR\.I\c{S}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it is correct. Actually it worked again. But i can't understand what you did. Because it is very complicated for me. How can i learn these things on my own?

Comment: @mfc - I can highly recommend the book "The LaTeX Companion". (It's from that book that I learned about the low-level macro `\@seccntformat`.) It's not a short book, to be sure. However, it's chockful of really good insights and explanations. I've had this book for 10 years or more, I've have read most chapters multiple times, and I still learn new stuff when I go through it anew.

Comment: Than you very much.